# Why is [ -n $var ] true on empty string?

Tags: linux, bash

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXISTS=""

echo ${#EXISTS} #print size of string

if [ -n $EXISTS ]; then
    echo "It exists!"
else
    echo "It is empty."
fi

if [ -z $EXISTS ]; then
    echo "It is empty."
else
    echo "It exists!"
fi
```

Output:

```
0
It exists!
It is empty.
```

From `man bash`:

> -z string
>
> > True if the length of string is zero.
>
> -n string
>
> > True if the length of string is non-zero.

Could someone explain this behavior of -n to me, and why it doesn't agree with -z? Thanks!

Comment: So I just realized this is more about the brackets - this works as expected with double brackets.

Comment: It is a bit of both. See the answer and my comment.

Comment: @EtanReisner your comment was super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It's almost better to ignore `[` and always use `test` (or even better, use `[[ ... ]]` when available and POSIX compatibility isn't a concern). You're less likely to be surprised by how the arguments to `test` are handled (because it actually *looks* like a command), and you don't need the ridiculous final `]` argument whose only purpose is to further the illusion that `[` is some sort of syntax.

Comment: Didn't we tell you to use quotes on your last question on this topic?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy maybe...*pulls collar* slow learner I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EXISTS=""
if [ -n $EXISTS ]; then
    ...
fi
```

The behavior of `[ ... ]` depends on the number of arguments before the closing `]`.

If there's exactly one argument, it tests whether that argument is non-empty. Since the string `"-n"` is non-empty, `[ -n ]` is true. `-n` is interpreted as an operator only if it's followed by another argument.

To fix this, quote the argument so it's interpreted as a single empty argument, rather than as no argument:

```
if [ -n "$EXISTS" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Quote the variable or better use `[[...]]` in BASH:

```
if [[ -n $EXISTS ]]; then echo "It exists!"; else echo "It is empty."; fi
```

It will print:

```
It is empty.
```

Similarly:

```
if [ -n "$EXISTS" ]; then echo "It exists!"; else echo "It is empty."; fi
It is empty.
```

Comment: Specifically this is because when `$EXISTS` is unquoted and the shell expands the variable in `[ -n $EXISTS ]` it becomes `[ -n ]` which is interpreted by `[`/`test` as `[ -n -n ]` (see the man page) whereas `[[` doesn't have that empty variable problem and the quotes make it see `[ -n '' ]`.